# Using :not() with attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to grab all select elements which do not have the "multiple" attribute set. I tried with the :not() but I can't get it quite right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select:not(multiple)').select2();
});
```

Comment: It doesn’t change syntax… `select:not([multiple])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the attribute selector. What you're looking for there is "a `<select>` that is not a `<multiple>`"

```
$("select:not([multiple])").select2();
```

Comment: damn, I was so close. It worked though, thank you very much.

Comment: How are you so fast? Absol only has a base speed of 75.. :p

Comment: @JoshC Um... er... er... Choice Scarf?

Comment: No, wait. Sucker Punch. 50% crit chance too ^_^

Answer (score 2):

`$('select:not([multiple])').select2();`

or

`$('select').not('[multiple]').select2();`